# Android replace fragment from one to another is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am trying to open a fragment on button click. Button click is already in a fragment. So what I trying to do is to open a fragment from another fragment. I google it thoroughly and found this code

```
    FragmentInner_Add_Location fragment = new FragmentInner_Add_Location();
    FragmentTransaction transaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

i got this error in replace method.

```
Wrong second argument type. Found com.(my package name) required android.support.v4.app.fragment.
```

I really dont understand the issue here. Am I missing something?
Here is my other fragment code (The fragment I am trying to call)

```
public class FragmentInner_Add_Location extends Fragment  {
    View view;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    //------------ make your specific key ------------
    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDLUTzdwYKCFKpnMWKGTCaC_TnleKeKFSU";
    public FragmentInner_Add_Location() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_fav_location_main_layout, null);
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_auto_complete_location);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_inner_add_location_row_items));
//      autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener();
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String str = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;



    }
    public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:gr");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

            System.out.println("URL: "+url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {

            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

}
```

Comment: `import android.support.v4.app.fragment;` in your `Fragment`

Comment: use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead of this `import android.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your fragment as:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```